# flex builder 3 : how to create automatically dateadd day/month/year process in datefield

Tags: apache-flex, dateadd, datefield

i was trying to create automatically add day but result still math calculation not date calculation. example if you create +14 and you choose date 20-11-2016 the result should be 04-12-2016 but my function result still math calculation and result 34-11-2016. thanks for your help.sorry bad english

```
private function useDate(df_start:CalendarLayoutChangeEvent):void {
        // Make sure selectedDate is not null.
        if (df_start.currentTarget.selectedDate == null) {
            return 
        }

        //Access the Date object from the event object.         
        df_target.text=df_start.currentTarget.selectedDate.getFullYear() +'-'+
                        (df_start.currentTarget.selectedDate.getMonth()+ 1) +'-'+
                       (df_start.currentTarget.selectedDate.getDate() + 14);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using getDate() method, it is only returning the Number and thats why you are getting numerical operation. Use the Date.date method to set date as below.

```
        private function useDate(df_start:CalendarLayoutChangeEvent):void {
        // Make sure selectedDate is not null.
        if (df_start.currentTarget.selectedDate == null) {
            return 
        }

        var date1:Date = df_start.currentTarget.selectedDate;
        date1.date +=14;

        //Access the Date object from the event object.         
        df_target.text=date1.getFullYear() +'-'+
                   date1.getMonth() +'-'+
                   date1.getDate();

}
```

Comment: this function still have a problem in month. you know that getMonth in flex need +1 and how to +1 for month? i was trying to create new var with +1 but not working. thanks for help by the way.

Comment: For getMonth you can do date1.getMonth() + 1. That is ok as month starts from 0 in actionscript.                                                             df_target.text=date1.getFullYear() +'-'+
                  (df_start.currentTarget.selectedDate.getMonth()+ 1) +'-'+
                   date1.getDate();